# Можно ли ArrayList с числами сохранить в SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Ребят, у меня есть ArrayList с 12 числами, как его можно сохранить SharedPreferences? ведь там идет работа с примитивными типами?

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно сохранить JSON строку используя Gson.

вот так например

```
new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, [вот пример](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/05/string-arrays-and-object-arrays-in.html):

```
public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) { 
  SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);
  for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);
  return editor.commit();
}
```